# Java и клиентские сертификаты

Tags: ssl, java

В данный момент на сайте используется технология входа по клиентским сертификатам через браузер средствами Apache, но пришлось переходить на Java сервер через сокеты с агентом Flash. Мы никак не можем понять, как нам реализовать в такой ситуации работу клиентских сертификатов, ситуация практически тупиковая. Разработка своего JAVA приложения для сайта возможна, но там опять-таки не понятно, как работать с хранилищем сертификатов Windows (А в Mac OS?), если это вообще возможно.
Как в нашей ситуации возможно было бы реализовать авторизацию посредству клиентских сертификатов?

Comment: Вы хотите брать сертификаты из локальной машины или из сервера?

Comment: В вашем случае Java приложение может иметь свою базу сертификатов, независимую от операционной системы.